# perl np++ messes up chars

Tags: perl, encoding

How can this character representation in the original file:

```
" – "
```

be displayed as this using perl script in the output console of np++ ?

```
" ÔÇô "
```

The original encoding is UTF-8 (according to np++) and to open and read in the file I use this line:

```
open(DATA, '<:encoding(utf-8)', "C:\\test.csv") or die "Can't open data";
@lines = <DATA>;
```

If i iterate over lines with:

```
foreach (@lines){
  print $_;
}
```

the character is representad as mentioned above. I display the ouput in the notepad++ console not in a new file.

Comment: Try `use utf8;` at the top of your script.

Comment: Hi. I do use use utf8; Forgot to mention that.

Comment: By np++ you mean notepad++? Open file in np++ and check if the "Encoding" (in menu bar) is same for both input and output file.

Comment: input: utf-8 output: console (no encoding)

Comment: try to print the results in a file, I think your console is behaving differently

Comment: I tried it but did not work. The character is wrong in the file too.

Comment: `DATA` is a special handle. Use another name in the future. In fact, why are you using a global variable. `my $DATA` and `<$DATA>` would solve both problems.

Answer (score 1):

Before your `print` statement, try to add this:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
foreach (@lines){
  print $_;
}
```

On Windows systems,

```
use Encode; 
binmode(STDOUT, 'encoding(cp850)');
```

the code page (850) number in your system may be different, write this order in a DOS console to get yours:

```
C:\>chcp
```

That said, it might now work even if you do everything right because the character in question, U+2013, is not part of the two most common console encodings, [cp850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp850) and [cp437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp437). It cannot be displayed in consoles using those encodings.

If that's the case, your best bet is switching the console's encoding to UTF-8 by entering `chcp 65001` at the prompt. You'll need to edit the console's properties to switch the font to an appropriate font (e.g. Lucidia Console). After doing that, you can use `:encoding(UTF-8)`.

Comment: I have this statement too at the beginning.

Comment: Hi. I get codepage: 850. But if I use it in binmode(STDOUT, 'encoding(cp850)'; it still does not work. I get now \x{2013}.

Comment: try to execute in a Windows console (maybe a issue with np++)

Comment: @user3483676, That's because the character in question, U+2013, is not part of [cp850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). It cannot be displayed by your console. See update.